# How to import large size database into phpmyadmin

Tags: database, import, phpmyadmin, migration, web-hosting

We have our website on ipage.com hosting. We are planing to move our entire website (i.e. in joomla cms) from ipage hosting to our godaddy VPS.

So our godaddy VPS hosting is ready.
We already exported our database (i.e. in .sql file) from phpmyadmin which is almost around 300Mb in size.

How to import that large size of database file into my server (in phpmyadmin).

I had done migration process before, but only with small size of database and all...

Could you please suggest me what can i do for importing this large size (i.e. arount 300Mb) of database into our godaddy VPS phpmyadmin.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please help me, i am just waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a VPS, you *could* modify any PHP or webserver restrictions on memory usage and execution timeouts...

But, since it's a VPS, I'd just use the command-line tools. You can upload the .sql file through whatever file transfer means you have configured (ssh/scp, sftp, netcat/nc, etc) and use the MySQL command line tool to handle the import. That way, you won't have to worry about any of the webserver/PHP resource limits that might cause trouble by importing such a file through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I had used SSH method for importing large database in MySQL, Thanks for your great support